# Mechanical Turk File Upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to test file uploads on Mechanical Turk.

I'm calling the GetFileUploadURL service and my query string looks something like this:

```
Operation=GetFileUploadURL&AssignmentId=XXX&Signature=XXX&Version=2008-08-02&AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Timestamp=2009-07-11T18%3A33%3A03-04%3A00&QuestionIdentifier=smiley&HITId=XXX&Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester
```

My HIT HTML looks like this

```
<ul>
    <li>Draw me a smily face.</li>
    <li>Save it as a PNG</li>
    <li>Image must be 64x64</li>
    <li>Be Creative</li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><input type="file" name="smiley" value="" /></p>
```

I'm getting an error back that `"The value \"null\" is not valid for the parameter QuestionIdentifier"` even though I *am* passing the `QuestionIdentifier` in.

I'm guessing that my HIT HTML is not the most ideal and that I'm missing something that would have made this a lot easier. Could I have written something other than `<input type="file" name="smiley" value="" />` or improved it in some way that this web service call would be easier? <s>I'm really not sure what I was supposed to pass in my `GetFileUploadURL` call for `QuestionIdentifier` and I assumed that `"smiley"` would work.</s>

edit: I *know* that its supposed to be `smiley` base upon the results I see when I call `GetAssignmentsForHIT`.

Any ideas? Why does it think its null? Does order matter when passing parameters to this service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetFileUploadURLOperation.html):

> The GetFileUploadURL operation
>   generates and returns a temporary URL.
>   You use the temporary URL **to retrieve
>   a file uploaded by a Worker** as an
>   answer to a FileUploadAnswer question
>   for a HIT. For information about the
>   FileUploadAnswer answer, see
>   QuestionForm.

So this method is for retrieving files that have already been uploaded. It sounds as though you are trying to perform the upload with this method which is incorrect. As the documentation says, see [QuestionForm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html) and the details on `FileUploadAnswer`to find out how the upload should work

Comment: It looks like I could *not* generate a file-upload question from the template-based HIT designer. However, when I clicked on "create HIT's individually" I got a nice little button that allowed me to add a file-upload control and everything worked as documented. So, yeah, I guess I was using the wrong control.

Now... how do I add that control from the templated-based designer? I want to know because the "manage individually" designer seems to allows only one control on the form.